# Замена слова в строке, Python

Tags: python, replace

Всем привет, только учуь пайтону, так что не судите строго.
Написал функцию, по поиску и замены слова в строке на пустышку, все работает, но если после слова идет запятая, не работает, гуглил много, но простого решения проблемы не нашел:

```
def f_del(*args):
    new_text = a
    for i in args:

        new_text = new_text.replace(i + ' ', '')


    return new_text
```

буду благодарен ответ.

Comment: используйте регулярки https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

Ну можно же просто добавить строчку

```
new_text = new_text.replace(i + ', ', '')
```

И так для всех остальных знаков препинания.

*PS. Совет нехороший, не нужно им пользоваться.*